# Rotated element makes twitter bootstrap Tooltip/Popover render incorrectly (with an offset)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

There is a bug in Bootstrap when using tooltip or popovers on a rotated element.
When using the CSS below, the tooltip is displayed with a big offset.

```
transform: rotate(270deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
-o-transform: rotate(270deg);
margin-top: 59px;
width: 100px;
position: relative;
left: -40px;
top: -90px;
```

I think the tooltip is appearing where the element would be if it wasn't rotated, but the thing that drives me crazy is that it used to work fine with an older version of bootstrap, which I cannot use since it brings other non related bugs into my code.

NOT WORKING (Version Currently v3.2.0)
http://jsfiddle.net/urielzen/7xf9m914/

WORKING FINE (OLD VERSION)
http://jsfiddle.net/urielzen/gh0yuo7w/

I have tried comparing the two bootstrap JavaScript files to see if I could just change the part that makes it render correctly, but I haven't figured out where is the fix.

I submitted the issue already, but in the meanwhile I wanted to see if anyone as any workaround to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenting these lines in the bootstrap.js will fix this... until an official solution is implemented in a new version.

```
  width:  isBody ? $(window).width()  : $element.outerWidth(),
  height: isBody ? $(window).height() : $element.outerHeight()
```

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14553